# Launch native Android app from AIR app on Kindle

Tags: android, android-intent, air, adobe, navigatetourl

I have a set of applications running on Kindle Fire:  a Main app which is written in Java and the other apps are written in Flash (AS3) for AIR.  Through the intents mechanism, I am able to launch the AIR app from the Main app.  I would like the AIR app to return to the Main app when the user clicks on a particular button.

It is mandated that this must run on Kindle Fire, and I've determined that Kindle Fire will not run AIR version 3.0 or newer.  This ruled out one promising link which suggested that AIR supports intents in 3.0, but not in earlier releases.

For now, I've been playing with `navigateToURL(new URLRequest( < app url > ))`, but this causes a security sandbox error and many of the websites I've read suggest that there's no way to make this work.

So, is there a way to get my AIR app to invoke the native Android app?  Any insight you could offer would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.